# FB.ui 'apprequest' not working anymore on mobile devices?

Tags: facebook, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk

This code worked well in many Facebook apps on mobile devices:

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'some message'
}, function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

But not anymore. The dialog opens up, but its not loading friendslist to send the apprequest.

No errors, no changes from my side. Seems like Facebook dropped some kind of mobile support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the following bug report: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1483731408567352/

Can you confirm that it is the same? If so, please subscribe to that bug report to stay posted.